# Is it possible to drag drop images with touch screen device

Tags: html, tablet

My HTML5 application lets you drag and drop images from another webpage. But when using PC in tablet mode I cannot seem to drag images, surely this must be possible in 2018?

If it really is not possible, what alternative mechanism can I use to allow User to use the image from another website?

Comment: Have you tried tap-and-drag?

Comment: @TrippKinetics   how do i do that, I'm trying to drag an image from a google image search results page.

Comment: You go like you're going to double-click on the image, but you don't let go of the second click.  You drag from there.

Comment: @TrippKinetics it seems to just open the page the mage is on?

Comment: You mean that the image doesn't get dragged along as long as you keep your finger down?

Comment: @TrippKinetics If do a quick first tap then as soon as I let go it just opens the image Whilst I'm trying to 2nd tap. If instead I hold first tap down it greys out but I'm still unable to drag it. You do realize I mean when using touchscreen not trackpad

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: @TrippKinetics Windows 10

Comment: I've been trying with Android and it's been working.  Next time I'm in front of Windows 10, I'll take a look.

Comment: @TrippKinetics im now trying on my Android phone and have same problem, i must be misunderstanding what you mean, but I dont know in whhat way.

Comment: you just need to tap and hold your finger on the image for 2-3 seconds then slowly drag the image to where ever you want. It works for me.

Answer (score 6):

Please look into this:

```
var draggable = document.getElementById('draggable');
    draggable.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
    var touch = event.targetTouches[0];
    
    // Place element where the finger is
    draggable.style.left = touch.pageX-25 + 'px';
    draggable.style.top = touch.pageY-25 + 'px';
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Also, here is a tutorial: http://mobiforge.com/design-development/touch-friendly-drag-and-drop

Please let me know if it works or if you need any more `help` with that :)

Edit: Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uw8ofs8t/1/) with a test I built a while before. I've updated it with comments so you should see what's going on there. Maybe a JavaScript pro would want to hit me for this, but it's working for my purpose and it seems to work. I haven't tested it in older browsers though, since it's a personal project and I'm not going the "optimizing for IE way" there.